# jsonRequest is delayed

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

I have a jsonRequest function which I'll use for Login. The function will change a boolean (named flag) whether there's a successful query or not. I call the function on attemptLogin function which is inside Button OnClickListener.

It seems like the jsonRequest function is not called at the first time (the boolean didn't changed). But on the second try, with same input, the boolean is changed. Later I found that the jsonRequest function is called after the boolean checking.

Anyone know how to fix this ? I'll post the code below. Thank you :)

The jsonRequest function (can't post the url, but it works):

```
public void jsonRequest()  {

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                           // response
                     Log.d("Response", response);
                    if (response.equals("success")) {
                        flag = true;
                        Log.d ("flag2", String.valueOf(flag));
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", mEmailView.getText().toString());
            params.put("pass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

This is where I call the jsonRequest, and the boolean checking.

```
if( ! password.isEmpty() && ! email.isEmpty()) {

        jsonRequest();


        Log.e("FLAG", String.valueOf(flag));

        if (flag == true) {
            cancel = false;
        }
        else {
            cancel = true;
            mPasswordView.setText("");
            focusView = mEmailView;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: what is the default value of flag?

Comment: the default value is false.

Comment: This is because you jsonRequest() method execute in different thread. Till the time your method invocation  is done. Adjust the method to onResponse of you request.

Comment: Volley generates an asynchronous request, so the code after `jsonRequest();` gets executed before you get a response. You should move that logic inside the `onResponse`

Comment: i tried that too (Ganesh Tikone's answer below) and it can change the flag to false. But after that the login still happens as the flag is true. The "invalid password" Toast is showing too.

Comment: @bravevctr did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if condition` is always `false` because you are not updating the default value assigned to it i.e `flag` is `false`.

Try this

```
if( !( password.isEmpty() &&  email.isEmpty())) {

            jsonRequest();

            Log.e("FLAG", String.valueOf(flag));

            cancel = false;
            }
            else {
            cancel = true;
           // mPasswordView.setText("");
            focusView = mEmailView;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
```

and in jsonRequest();

```
public void jsonRequest()  {

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                           // response
                     Log.d("Response", response);
                    if (response.equals("success")) {
                        flag = true;
                        Log.d ("flag2", String.valueOf(flag));
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", mEmailView.getText().toString());
            params.put("pass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, every request made through volley is asynchronous, onResponse and onError callback execute on UI thread, so your code is corrected here.

```
 public void jsonRequest()  {

  StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                       // response
                 Log.d("Response", response);
                if (response.equals("success")) {
                    flag = true;
                    Log.d ("flag2", String.valueOf(flag));
                    cancel = false;      

                }
                else {
                    flag = false;
                    cancel = true;
                    mPasswordView.setText("");  
                    focusView = mEmailView;   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error
                Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
                //TODO: Please handle error scenario, which is missing.    
            }
        }
  ) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("email", mEmailView.getText().toString());
        params.put("pass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());

        return params;
    }
};
queue.add(postRequest); 
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it can change the flag to false. But after that the login still happens as the flag is true. The "invalid password" Toast is showing too.

Comment: Your login logic should depend on OnResponse flag. As your code was partial, I am not able to understand it.